# iOS11 scenekit ,how to set blur background?

Tags: scenekit

I watched the session of WWDC17 and know what's new in scenekit. A part of them is the change of depth of field.
I use the below code to create blur background but It doesn't work
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fStop of 5.6 is only going to create noticeable DOF effects with long zoom lenses above 300mm in traditional camera terms.

You'll need a much wider aperture. Something like 1.4 or 2.0 should make for significantly noticeable DOF effects if you're using a lens that's somewhere between 50 - 300mm in "zoom" length. For wider angle lenses, you'll maybe need to use unrealistic numbers like 1.0 or even 0.8 aperture.

From this site: https://www.exposureguide.com/focusing-basics/

[image]

A good image to show the significant difference at the lower numbers of aperture in terms of the gaping hole size. The easiest way to think of it is an aperture of 1.0 = a hole the size of the lens. Larger numbers = smaller holes, and longer DOF.

'Here's a table that shows basic Focal Length to Angle of View numbers (35mm equiv)

```
+--------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Focal Length | AOV Hor | AOV Vert | AOV Diag |
+--------------+---------+----------+----------+
|           15 |   100.4 |     77.3 |    110.5 |
|           24 |    73.7 |     53.1 |     84.1 |
|           35 |    54.4 |     37.8 |     63.4 |
|           50 |    39.6 |     27.0 |     46.8 |
|           85 |    23.9 |     16.1 |     28.6 |
|          135 |    15.2 |     10.2 |     18.2 |
|          200 |    10.3 |      6.9 |     12.3 |
|          300 |     6.9 |      4.6 |      8.2 |
|          500 |     4.1 |      2.7 |      5.0 |
|          800 |     2.6 |      1.7 |      3.1 |
+--------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank.So,In the scenekit,What parameter should I change to make a blur effect like the right part of the image in the question?

Comment: What are your current settings?

Comment: //the position of camearNode
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 2, z: 10)
cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(1, 0, 0, Float(-Double.pi/10))
//the position of SKNode
Node1.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
Node2.position = SCNVector3(x: 2, y: 0, z: -5)
//set the camera
camera.wantsDepthOfField = true
camera.focusDistance = 0.8
camera.fStop = 5.6

I only want to see the Node1 and blur the Node2

Comment: I set the fStop to 1.0,but there is no blur effct to any node

Comment: I set the fStop to 1.0,but there is no blur effct to any node

Comment: Can you please give me demo code to implement the blur effect?for example,change the parameter of camera in Xcode's scenekit template to implement the blur effect?

Comment: oh.I get it! The blur effct is no effct on the simulator.

Comment: Well done! You had me boggled and confused. I couldn't figure out why you weren't seeing it. I never use the simulator, it's got too many problems. Instead, I build to both Mac and Device, and when I need to fast iterative development/testing, I build to the Mac, since that runs almost immediately, much faster than the Simulator starting up.

Comment: If you have any more questions about Scene Kit, ping me in the comments with an @xuekedou. The @ will notify me.